# Query to select sth with another select

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a query but I'm experiencing troubles with syntax and I haven't found a solution for it.

```
 $reponse = $bdd->query('
 SELECT * 
   FROM web_pages
  WHERE company_token = 
    ( SELECT token 
        FROM pro_users 
       WHERE id ='{$_SESSION["id"]}'
    )
 ');
```

That is my code and it's working but when I'm adding WHERE id ='{$_SESSION["id"]}')', syntax troubles appear. what should i modify ?

Comment: Explain what tumbles  means. Besides this looks **vulnerable**  to **sql injection** see if your system desn't support  **prepared statements with oarameters**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to do something like this

```
 $reponse = $bdd->query("SELECT * FROM web_pages WHERE company_token = (SELECT token FROM pro_users WHERE id ='".$_SESSION["id"]."')");
```

But this is dangerous and vulnerable see this [SQL INJECTION](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection)
I suggest you to protect your query and use prepare statement like this

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM web_pages WHERE company_token = (SELECT token FROM pro_users WHERE id = ?)");
$reponse->execute(array($_SESSION["id"]));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will work about SQL injection

Comment: Please remember to come back and mark my answer as accepted (accepted score better in search so others can find it easier)

Comment: Roger ---------------------